# MySQL 64 bits? Stand alone?

Tags: mysql, 64-bit

To extent my understanding on MySQL.

1) Is going for 64bit help? Do I go with installation or stand alone?

2) If I am going to use 64-bit in MySQL Community Service, will it affect the MySQL Workbench which only available in 32-bit? If yes, in what sense?

3) Does the size of the file affect the speed of MySQL when doing calculation, analysis, and graph? I get a lot of big trouble using Excel in big size.

Please guide.

Note: I am working on excel database (which I found out on this website that it is not a good way to do it) with size of 1.34GB 63 files and growing. I would like to change and continue working in MySQL. I need the database for calculation, analysis and graph.

Comment: Related. stackoverflow.com/questions/3240928/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing a few concepts. But let me first answer your questions.

1/ 64-bit is more powerful than 32-bit, if your server supports 64-bit. So yes, it should "help".

2/ You can use a 64-bit server with a 32-bit client without any problems. They just communicate with eachother using MySQL-statements, bitsize makes no difference there.

3/ The size of the file (table/row/...) does matter. A lot of small tables can outperform one big table in certain cases, especially with multicore/raid/...

Comment: You see I dont know anything about MySQL. Now I see it.

Comment: What if I have rows of 1 million and 50+ column?